# Bootstrap-Vue CSS compilation in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-mix, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Laravel 5.6, Laravel Mix 2.0, and Bootstrap-Vue 2.0.0-rc.1.

Trying to find a way to configure Laravel Mix to include Bootstrap-Vue's CSS into my `app.css` file and prevent Bootstrap-Vue from including `<style>` tags into the page `<head>`.

I saw this note in the package docs but still not sure how to use this properly:

> **Note**: requires webpack configuration to load css files ([official guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found a solution - [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin).

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1589

Answer (score 1):

Install:

1. npm i bootstrap-vue
2. npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader

Use:

edit resources/js/app.js to:

1. import Vue from 'vue'
2. import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
3. Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

edit resources/sass/app.scss to:

4. Import the styles:

   - import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
   - import '~bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Make sure the app.js and app.css are included in the blade(view) that is acting as the container for your vue.
See: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/

Comment: I was asking about the CSS. Both, JS and CSS, are working fine for me. Just want to move CSS from `<style>` tags into my compiled CSS file.

Comment: @Roman Tolstoy, you just have to add:
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Comment: This doesn't help to get rid of `<style>` tags inserted into `<head>` by BootstrapVue.

Comment: @RomanTolstoy so you want to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/stylesheet">` instead of `<style>/** shit tons of injected css **/</style>`?

Comment: I **am** using the compiled `app.css` file already (the resulting file with all the CSS compiled by Laravel Mix). I just want all these inline styles from the Bootstrap-Vue components to be included in the `app.css` instead of bloating the page size.